# Proof of an equation in vector calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, integration-by-parts

How do I prove the following by integration by parts:

$$\iiint \left( \vec{\triangledown} . \dfrac{\vec{I}}{r} \right)dV=\iint\dfrac{1}{r} \vec{I}.\hat{n} dS-\iiint\dfrac{1}{r} \left( \vec{\triangledown} . \vec{I} \right)dV$$

given that:

$$\vec{\triangledown}.\left( \dfrac{\vec{I}}{r}\right)=\vec{\triangledown}\dfrac{1}{r} . \vec{I} + \dfrac{1}{r} \vec{\triangledown}.\vec{I}$$

Comment: i think maybe it has to do something with divergence theorem

Comment: If you mean a scalar product, use a 'central dot' LaTeX `\cdot`, rendered as $A \cdot B$ instead of a normal 'decimal dot'.

Comment: Hint: Rearrange your equation so that the triple integrals are on one side and the double integral is on the other.